# How to print a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I want to print the result of grouping with Pandas.

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'one'], 'B': range(6)})
print(df)

       A  B
0    one  0
1    one  1
2    two  2
3  three  3
4  three  4
5    one  5
```

When printing after grouping by 'A' I have the following:

```
print(df.groupby('A'))

<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x05416E90>
```

How can I print the dataframe grouped?

If I do:

```
print(df.groupby('A').head())
```

I obtain the dataframe as if it was not grouped:

```
             A  B
A                
one   0    one  0
      1    one  1
two   2    two  2
three 3  three  3
      4  three  4
one   5    one  5
```

I was expecting something like:

```
             A  B
A                
one   0    one  0
      1    one  1
      5    one  5
two   2    two  2
three 3  three  3
      4  three  4
```

Comment: I am getting correct output with `print df.groupby('A').head()`. what version of pandas do you have?

Comment: I just updated to 0.13.1 on both my desktop and laptop.

Comment: How about to "list()" the object directly? And then you can manipulate/print it as a normal data structure.

Comment: As far as I can tell, not a single answer manages to produce the desired output. For this specific example, the closest I could find was `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum()`, but it would fail if `('A', 'B')` pairs aren't unique.

Comment: Hello. Can I know how to print "one" , "two" , "three" only in the output? What  I mean  is only print the data that we have grouped. I want to use this data to label my pie chart.

Answer (score 148):

Simply do:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('A')

for key, item in grouped_df:
    print(grouped_df.get_group(key), "\n\n")
```

---

> **Deprecation Notice**: `ix` was [deprecated in 0.20.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#deprecate-ix)

This also works,

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('A')    
gb = grouped_df.groups

for key, values in gb.iteritems():
    print(df.ix[values], "\n\n")
```

**For selective key grouping:** Insert the keys you want inside the `key_list_from_gb`, in following, using `gb.keys()`: For Example,

```
gb = grouped_df.groups
gb.keys()

key_list_from_gb = [key1, key2, key3]

for key, values in gb.items():
    if key in key_list_from_gb:
        print(df.ix[values], "\n")
```

Comment: Another option is: `for A in d['A'].unique(): print(A, df.query(f'A == "{A}"'))`

Comment: __iter__(）also works. It returns Generator yielding sequence of (name, subsetted object) for each group

Comment: Why not loop over `key_list_from_gb` though?

Answer (score 96):

If you're simply looking for a way to display it, you could use describe():

```
grp = df.groupby['colName']
grp.describe()
```

This gives you a neat table.

Comment: It's a neat table but it isn't the desired table.

Comment: Think you need to use parenthesis around ```['colName']``` so it is ```grp = df.groupby(['colName'])```

Comment: `df.groupby('colName')` works if you only have one grouping column

Answer (score 83):

In addition to previous answers:

Taking your example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'one'], 'B': range(6)})
```

Then simple 1 line code

```
df.groupby('A').apply(print)
```

Comment: Clever, although it would be better to .apply(display) to have a nice formatting.

Comment: Just import `display` from `Ipython.display` for that :)

Answer (score 28):

In Jupyter Notebook, if you do the following, it prints a nice grouped version of the object. The `apply` method helps in creation of a multiindex dataframe.

```
by = 'A'  # groupby 'by' argument
df.groupby(by).apply(lambda a: a[:])
```

Output:

```
             A  B
A                
one   0    one  0
      1    one  1
      5    one  5
three 3  three  3
      4  three  4
two   2    two  2
```

If you want the `by` column(s) to not appear in the output, just drop the column(s), like so.

```
df.groupby(by).apply(lambda a: a.drop(by, axis=1)[:])
```

Output:

```
         B
A         
one   0  0
      1  1
      5  5
three 3  3
      4  4
two   2  2
```

Here, I am not sure as to why `.iloc[:]` does not work instead of `[:]` at the end. So, if there are some issues in future due to updates (or at present), `.iloc[:len(a)]` also works.

Comment: I have a df where I needed to set the index to group, so for this to work I had to use `.apply(lambda a: a.reset_index())`

Answer (score 19):

```
df.groupby('A').apply(display)
```

gives neat formatting

Comment: What's display?

Comment: Underrated. @misantroop it's a display function from Jupyter

Comment: The question wasn't about Jupyter and neither is it tagged.

Answer (score 17):

I confirmed that the behavior of `head()` changes between version 0.12 and 0.13. That looks like a bug to me. I created an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6721).

But a groupby operation doesn't actually return a DataFrame sorted by group. The `.head()` method is a little misleading here -- it's just a convenience feature to let you re-examine the object (in this case, `df`) that you grouped. The result of `groupby` is separate kind of object, a `GroupBy` object. You must `apply`, `transform`, or `filter` to get back to a DataFrame or Series.

If all you wanted to do was sort by the values in columns A, you should use `df.sort('A')`.

Comment: note that ``head`` is actually doing ``head(5)`` iow it is showing the first 5 rows, more correct to 'show' frame is ``df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x)``, which is effectively a passthru. I suppose you could have a ``pass()`` method, maybe.

Answer (score 16):

Another simple alternative:

```
for name_of_the_group, group in grouped_dataframe:
   print (name_of_the_group)
   print (group)
```

Answer (score 11):

Also, other simple alternative could be:

```
gb = df.groupby("A")
gb.count() # or,
gb.get_group(your_key)
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Surya for good insights. I'd clean up his solution and simply do:

```
for key, value in df.groupby('A'):
    print(key, value)
```

Answer (score 5):

Call list() on the GroupBy object

```
print(list(df.groupby('A')))
```

gives you:

```
[('one',      A  B
0  one  0
1  one  1
5  one  5), ('three',        A  B
3  three  3
4  three  4), ('two',      A  B
2  two  2)]
```

Comment: Yeah, this needs more votes! You can do this also after you grouped the object. df_g = df.groupby('A') then you can call list(df_g) or if you just want the first group call list(df_g)[0].

This is one thing I like about R over Python.  In R you don't have to iterate through most object to see the data, but Python you have to on a lot of the object.  Finding proceses like this are refreshing.  Thanks Elizabeth.

Answer (score 3):

This is a better general purpose answer.  This function will print all group names and values, or optionally selects one or more groups for display.

```
def print_pd_groupby(X, grp=None):
    '''Display contents of a Panda groupby object
    :param X: Pandas groupby object
    :param grp: a list with one or more group names
    '''
    if grp is None:
        for k,i in X:
            print("group:", k)
            print(i)
    else:
        for j in grp:
            print("group:", j)
            print(X.get_group(j))
```

In your example case, here's session output

```
In [116]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'one'], 'B': range(6)})

In [117]: dfg = df.groupby('A')

In [118]: print_pd_groupby(dfg)
group: one
     A  B
0  one  0
1  one  1
5  one  5
group: three
       A  B
3  three  3
4  three  4
group: two
     A  B
2  two  2

In [119]: print_pd_groupby(dfg, grp = ["one", "two"])
group: one
     A  B
0  one  0
1  one  1
5  one  5
group: two
     A  B
2  two  2
```

This is a better answer because a function is re-usable content, put it in your package or function collection and never re-write that "scriptish" approach again.

IMHO, something like this should be a built in method in Pandas groupby.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot see the groupBy data directly by print statement but you can see by iterating over the group using for loop 
try this code to see the group by data

```
group = df.groupby('A') #group variable contains groupby data
for A,A_df in group: # A is your column and A_df is group of one kind at a time
  print(A)
  print(A_df)
```

you will get an output after trying this as a groupby result

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I found a tricky way, just for brainstorm, see the code:

```
df['a'] = df['A']  # create a shadow column for MultiIndexing
df.sort_values('A', inplace=True)
df.set_index(["A","a"], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

the output:

```
             B
A     a
one   one    0
      one    1
      one    5
three three  3
      three  4
two   two    2
```

The pros is so easy to print, as it returns a dataframe, instead of Groupby Object. And the output looks nice.
While the con is that it create a series of redundant data.

Answer (score 1):

**Assign the Groupby object a variable and use .first() method.** Example:

```
 a = df_apps_clean[['App', 'Installs']].groupby('Installs')
 a.first()  <----
```

Answer (score 0):

to print all (or arbitrarily many) lines of the grouped df:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)

grouped_df = df.group(['var1', 'var2'])
print(grouped_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to convert the DataFrameGroupBy object to list and you can simply print it..
ls_grouped_df = list(df.groupby('A'))
print(ls_grouped_df)

Answer (score -1):

use the get_group() method
you can have something like this

```
new_group = df.groupby(['A'])
get_group('')
```

put the name of the group you want to get inside the method