# How to count occurrence of each element in pandas series of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I'm a newbie and quite stuck with my python project. I have a pandas series containing lists, like this:

```
>> df.head()
>> column1       
   ['A', 'B']
   ['A']
   ['A', 'C']
   ['A', 'B', 'C']
   ['B']
```

The desired output should be like this:

```
>> column1   column2
    'A'         4
    'B'         3
    'C'         2
```

It doesn't matter whether **column1** is a string or a list with one element.

I tried these:

`df.groupby('column1').count()`

`df['column1'].value_counts()`

But both gave me:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Also tried:

`df.groupby('column1')`

But it does not display results.

Tried solutions here ([How to print a groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691010/how-to-print-a-groupby-object)) but none worked :(

Comment: Look at [`series.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and then do `value_counts` `df['column1'].explode().value_counts()`

Comment: Hello @anky, is this a new method? It returned: "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode' ". It's sad that I am not allowed to update the virtual machine I use. Will try it on my local machine. Will update soon. Thank you! :)

Comment: yes you need pandas `0.25` or above , or you can do `pd.Series(np.concatenate(df['column1'])).value_counts()`

Comment: Got it working now. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.explode('Column1').groupby('Column1').size().reset_index(name='Column2')
```

Output:

```
  Column1  Column2
0       A        4
1       B        3
2       C        2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df1['column1'].explode().groupby().count()
```

or

```
df1.explode('column1').groupby('column1').count()
```