# Understanding how to use lambda for panda's groupby.apply

Tags: python

Can someone explain how the unknown function lambda below knows to use the column label 'Year'? I was trying to adapt one of the solutions from this post:

Here is the image of the answer I was interested in from that post:
[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691010/how-to-print-a-groupby-object#]

and wanted to adapt the lambda to my code below:

```html
report = pd.DataFrame([
    [2009, 10, 'Einstein'],
    [2010, 20, 'Einstein'],
    [2010, 30, 'Einstein'],
    [2009, 10, 'Planck'],
    [2009, 20, 'Planck'],
    [2009, 30, 'Planck']], 
    index = ['r','o','y','g','b','i'],
    columns = ['Year', 'Points', 'Username'])

grouped = report.groupby('Year')
grouped = grouped.apply(lambda a: a[:])

grouped
```

Output:

[image]

I am trying learn how to what the lambda's function would be in this instance. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda function is here used as an anonymous function inside of another function.
`lambda a : a[:]` is the function that takes into input an iterrable type a and output `a[:]` :  every element of a.

`grouped = report.groupby('Year')` returns a groupby object that contains information about the groups formed by year.

`grouped = grouped.apply(lambda a: a[:])` apply on every "group" of your groupby object the anonymous function lambda.

So for every group of data sharing the same year you return all the data of this same group.
That is how you end up with a dataframe as index year (groupby('Year')) with for each year all the corresponding data.