# Groupby does return previous df without changing it

Tags: pandas

```
df=pd.read_csv('../input/tipping/tips.csv')
df_1 = df.groupby(['day','time'])
df_1.head()
```

Guys, what am I missing here ? As it returns to me previous dataframe without groupby

Comment: ? You've defered a call to [Groupby head](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) so you should be getting the first 5 rows from each group. What were you trying to do?

Comment: @HenryEcker trying to get a new df printed, as if use print(df_1) it will print me an object name

Comment: Right because `df_1` is a [GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html) object which provides support for fast aggregated indexing over DataFrame columns. Again, what were you trying to do with the `GroupBy` call?

Comment: @HenryEcker To groupby df by day,time columns and then output how new df will look like by df_1.head()

Comment: Do you mean [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)? Order the columns so that the day time values appear together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can print it using the following :

```py
df_1 = df.groupby(['day','time']).apply(print)
```

Comment: The issue with this is that `df_1` is going to be an empty DataFrame or just filled with `None` depending on the version of pandas. If wanting to print out separate DataFrames iterating over the groupby would make more sense. Beyond this if this _is_ the answer it's a duplicate of [How to print a groupby object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22691010/15497888)

Comment: Do you have a sample of data ?

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` doesn't work the way you are assuming by the sounds of it. Using `head` on the grouped dataframe takes the first 5 rows of the dataframe, even if it is across groups because that is how the groupby object is built. You can use @tlentali's approach to print out each group, but `df_1` will not be assigned the grouped dataframe that way, instead, `None` (the number of groups times) as that is the output of print.

The way below gives a lot of control over how to show/display the groups and their keys

```
This might also help you understand more about how the grouped data frame structure in pandas works.
df_1 = df.groupby(['day','time'])

# for each (day,time) and grouped data
for key, group in df_1:

    # show the (day,time) 
    print(key)

    # display head of the grouped data
    group.head()
```