# Group date by month

Tags: python

I try to group my data in monthly, and I use

```
wti_month = wti.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')),
```

but when I print the data it shows

`<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x12408d540>`

How this happen? and How can I print the data?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the data to look like after you group it?  You haven't performed any operations on the grouped data.

Comment: I would suggest using resample for `DatetimeIndex` grouping. eg: `wti.resample('M').sum()` (Or whatever type of aggregation you want) [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what are you trying to achieve but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691010/how-to-print-a-groupby-object) is how u can print your output , U can't just print **Dataframe objs**

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make any aggregations on the grouped data. If you only want to display it,
Do this:

```
wti_month = wti.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).apply(print)
```

Comment: So how can I make aggregation on the data

Comment: @Jayson we need to see other columns, for example if you want to calculate number of sales in each month, you can use .sum() like this: wti_month = wti.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))["sales"].sum()